# Intl error on Samsung browser

Tags: javascript, browser, angular

my web application (written Angular2 Rc1) works well on Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

But on my Galaxy s6, using the default browser, I get the following error:

[image]

I added this script in the index:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.it,Intl.~locale.en"></script>
```

It solved the problem with Safari but on the Samsubg browser the proble persists.
Is there a way to fix it?

Thnaks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that this is a bug in Intl library.
[Here](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/issues/170) you can follow the bug

I just tried the code posted by MasDevProject and it works.
I think they will update the repo soon.